# Flutter:Array of Textformfield validator not working

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am working on an Array of Textformfields. The Array can be more than 50. I want to submit array of values to the server. The issue is when I execute validator it will be validating the first 8 in the array after that no error message. That too disappears when scrolling.  I posted my code below:

```
void validateAndSave() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {

      _formKey.currentState.save();
      print('Form is valid');
    }
    else {
    //  _formKey.currentState.
      print('form is invalid');
    }

  }

    Widget singleItemList(int index) {
    Item item = itemList[index];

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child:
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [






          Expanded(

            child:Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 10, 20),


              child: new TextFormField(
               controller: _controller[index],

              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,




                //onSubmitted: (text) {
              //  takeNumber(text, item.id);
              //},


                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) return 'value is required';

                },



                decoration: new InputDecoration(

                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.indigo)),




                  labelText: itemList[index].id,

                  suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
              ),


              ),
            ),
          ),


        ],
      ),


    );

  }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sathish

Comment: have you tried the use of `Tuple`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered replacing ListView.builder with Column?

Like this:

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: List.generate(itemList.length, (index) {
        if (itemList.isEmpty) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return singleItemList(index);
        }
      })
    ) 
  )
```

From ListView [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

> Destruction
>   
> **When a child is scrolled out of view, the associated element subtree, states and render objects are destroyed.** A new child at the same position in the list will be lazily recreated along with new elements, states and render objects when it is scrolled back.

Comment: Perfect alecsam works awesome. Thank you so much.Genius

Comment: Glad I could help!